# IIS url rewrite rule except home and some urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to remove www. from all requests and also redirect all requests from .info domain to .com domain except home page and some other urls like /usefulldoc/ but it's not working for the second rule.
This is my rules in web.config:

```
<rules>

    <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect .info to .com with some Exceptins"  stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example\.info$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example\.info(.*)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)/usefulldoc(.*)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"  />
    </rule>

  </rules>
```

Comment: Move the second rule to the top.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Track the original URL and rewritten URL via FRT, and the problem would then be clear.